# Battery status without activity only using broadcastreceiver

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-activity, battery

Hi I'm making an app which uses only the broadcast receiver. It serves three purposes. When a SMS containing specific code is received it sends the GPS data. The other code sends the sensor data. No problems up to this point. But for the battery I'm unable to do this because of the registerreceiver() function. As I'm not using an activity and onCreate method, can I send the battery data when an SMS is received?

When I tried to tweak this in the onreceive() method of broadcastreceiver, my application crashes. I searched everywhere an activity is created. I want to do everything inside the broadcast receiver only.

My code goes like this:

```
public class MyPhoneReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver{
double current_lat,current_lng;
LocationManager mlocManager;
LocationListener mlocListener;
//addition//////////////////////////////
SensorManager mSensorManager;

Sensor mAccelerometer;  
////////////////////

private static final String SMS_RECEIVED = "android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED";
private static final String TAG = "SMSBroadcastReceiver";

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
Log.i(TAG, "Intent recieved: rama" + intent.getAction());


Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
if (bundle != null) {
Object[] pdus = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");
final SmsMessage[] messages = new SmsMessage[pdus.length];
for (int i = 0; i < pdus.length; i++)
messages[i] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) pdus[i]);
if (messages.length > -1) {
String messagebody=messages[0].getMessageBody();
Log.i(TAG, "Message recieved: in message receied " + messages[0].getMessageBody());
if(messagebody.toString().matches("HDPK GPS"))
{
Log.i(TAG, "Message recieved: HDPK RECEIVED " + messages[0].getMessageBody());
mlocManager=(LocationManager)context.getSystemService(context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
mlocManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,1000,1,new MyLocationListener());
}
if(messagebody.toString().matches("HDPK SENS"))
{
Log.i(TAG, "Message recieved: in msensior ");
mSensorManager = (SensorManager)context.getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);
mAccelerometer = mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER);
mSensorManager.registerListener(new MySensorListener(), mAccelerometer, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
}
if(messagebody.toString().matches("HDPK BAT"))
{
Log.i(TAG, "Message recieved: in battery ");
IntentFilter filter=new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED);
Intent batt=context.registerReceiver(null,filter);
int level = batt.getIntExtra("EXTRA_LEVEL", 0);
Log.i(TAG, "Message recieved: in battery level is "+level);
SmsManager sender=SmsManager.getDefault();
sender.sendTextMessage("9762281814", null, "Level is"+level, null,null);
}



}
}
}

public class MySensorListener implements SensorEventListener
{
public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor arg0, int arg1) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
Log.i(TAG, "Message recieved: in msensior event change ");
float x = event.values[0];

float y = event.values[1];

float z = event.values[2];
SmsManager sender=SmsManager.getDefault();
String Text="x :"+x+" Y:"+y+ " Z:"+z;
sender.sendTextMessage("9762281814",null, Text, null, null);
mSensorManager.unregisterListener(this);
}

}

public class MyLocationListener implements LocationListener{

public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
current_lat=location.getLatitude();
current_lng=location.getLongitude();
SmsManager sender=SmsManager.getDefault();
String Text = "My Location is : Latitude ->" +current_lat+" Longitude ->" + current_lng;
sender.sendTextMessage("9762281814", null, Text, null, null);

mlocManager.removeUpdates(this);

}

public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub

}


}

}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try using the application `Context` instead of the broadcast receiver `Context` when using `registerReceiver()` to get the sticky battery changed `Intent`. Like this:

```
IntentFilter filter=new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED);
Intent batt=context.getApplicationContext().registerReceiver(null,filter);
int level = 99; // Default to some unknown/wild value
// registerReceiver method call could return null, so check that!
if (batt != null) {
    level = batt.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_LEVEL, 0);
}
```

Comment: I tried your code, but it is not working, do i need to give any kind of Permission for this ?

Comment: No, you don't need any permissions for that. What doyou mean "it isn not working"? What gets returned from the call to `registerReceiver()`? Any errors in the logcat?

Comment: Ya, i got it work now, but in my case i am using `level = batt.getIntExtra("level", 0);`  ,EXTRA_LEVEL is not working, my requirement was to check battery level from BroadcastReceiver, the other Activity one is successfully running, thanks for your help :)

Comment: Glad it is working now. If this answer was helpful you can accept it by clicking the green checkmark.

Comment: My fault. Sorry about that. My example code was flawed. I've edited the example code.

Comment: @Lucifer Ah, right. Sorry, didn't see that. I've updated my answer with the correct parameter. Should be `BatteryManager.EXTRA_LEVEL` instead of `"EXTRA_LEVEL"`.

Comment: again sorry, but `BatteryManager.EXTRA_LEVEL` is not working, it is giving error, there is no constant called EXTRA_LEVEL in BatteryManager class, but as i said "level" is working fine.

Comment: The constant `BatteryManager.EXTRA_LEVEL` is defined from API level 5 (Android 2.0). What SDK are you using?

Comment: oh ok, well i am working on Android 1.6, very basic one. I want to go for lower version only so that my application can work on many devices. Thanks for this nice information, i thought that Constant was removed, because i tried so much to implement it, also found on net at many place the same code.

Comment: Thanks for this answer! I'd been struggling for ages trying to figure out how to get the battery level in my BroadcastReceiver, not really sure why using the application context instead should make a difference, but if it works I won't complain! But just in case, can anyone summarise why using the application context instead of the one provided to the onReceive() method actually works?

Comment: @Haravikk that's an easy one. The `Context` that you get in `onReceive()` is short-lived. It lives only until the `onReceive()` method completes and then it is gone. Due to this, there are certain things you are not allowed to do with this `Context`. In general, you aren't allowed to do any asynchronous operations on this `Context` because it probably won't be around long enough for the asynchronous operations to complete. If you look at the Android source code, you will find that the `Context` that you get in `onReceive()` is actually a `ReceiverRestrictedContext`.

Comment: @Haravikk `ReceiverRestrictedContext ` throws a `ReceiverCallNotAllowedException` if you try to call `registerReceiver()` on it because, generally speaking, `registerReceiver()` is an asynchronous call. Interestingly enough, because you make this call providing `null` for the `BroadcastReceiver` parameter, it actually is a synchronous call, but I guess the Android developers forgot about that ;-)